# How to grant the USAGE privilege on all types?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, datatypes

How can I grant the USAGE privilege on ALL TYPES in a schema? For tables and functions we can use `ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name`, but [this isn't supported for types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html):

```
GRANT { USAGE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON TYPE type_name [, ...]
    TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

I know I can set a default privilege, but in this case I'd already installed an extension with many types before doing that.

Comment: When you say TYPE, do you mean types, domains, or both?

Comment: Very new to postgres, not sure what the correct terminology is. But I mean what's listed under 'Types' in a schema after you install an extension, when browsing with pgAdmin (for PostGIS e.g. 'geometry' and 'agg_count'). I found them listed in information_schema.data_type_privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with dynamic sql and psql, Sub out `user1` and `user2` with the name of the user. Feel free to delete either. You may also want only `DOMAIN` or `USER-DEFINED TYPE` adapting this should be pretty simple.

```
SELECT format(
  $$GRANT USAGE ON TYPE %s TO %s;$$,
  format('%I.%I.%I', object_catalog, object_schema, object_name ),
  grantUser
)
FROM information_schema.element_types
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('user1'),('user2')) AS t(grantUser)
WHERE object_type IN ('USER-DEFINED TYPE', 'DOMAIN');
```

Then run

```
\gexec
```

You can also run this in a `do` block with `PERFORM`